# After retrieving data from Firebase, how to send retrieved data from one view controller to another view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database

This is my table created in Firebase [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23438022/). I have a search button. The button action will be at first it will fetch data from firebase and then it will send it to another view controller and will show it in a table view. but main problem is that before fetching all data from Firebase

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SearchResultPage", sender: self )
```

triggers and my next view controller shows a empty table view. Here was my effort [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23440115/).

From this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780207/good-way-to-retrieve-information-from-firebase-swift) I think that my code is not placed well.

Answer (score 1):

Write this line of code in your dataTransfer method in if block after complete for loop

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SearchResultPage", sender: self )
```

Comment: Doesn't work.Please read carefully from this post. First You have to complete all operation from firebase. then you have trigger self.peformSe.....()   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780207/good-way-to-retrieve-information-from-firebase-swift

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the search string as the sender when you are performing the segue, for example:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SearchResultPage", sender: "searchString")
```

Then, in your prepare for segue get the destination view controller and send over the string to the new view controller. something like:

```
destinationViewController.searchString = sender as! String
```

When the segue is completed and you have come to the new view controller, you should now have a searchString value that is set, use this value to perform your query and get the relevant data to show in the new table view.

Please note that this is just one solution of many, there are other ways to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks. I did it before your solution. but I need the solution as expected. First it will fetch data then self.performSegueWithIdentifier() will be triggered.

Comment: @KhanShaheb Oh ok, then you will use a similar method, but instead you will get all the data and cast it as a dictionary, then you pass the dictionary as the sender in performSegue, then in prepareForSegue you pass the entire dictionary with all the results to the next view controller to be presented :)

Comment: in the time of fetching data.....self.performSegueWithIdentifier() begins. Thats why doesn't work. I need such type of closure or something that while fetching data everything will be frezzed and after complete loading everything will begin.

Comment: @KhanShaheb How are you fetching your data? there should be a completion handler somewhere, when data has been fetched then call performSegue, don't call it until it has been fetched

Comment: yes but as I am beginner...I am unable to use completion handler.

Comment: @KhanShaheb  could you provide code of how you are retrieving your data?

Answer (score 0):

- The reason why you are not able to send data is because, you are trying to send data even before the data could actually be fetched.
- Try the following where you are pushing to next view controller only after getting the data

  ```
  func dataTransfer() {

  let BASE_URL_HotelLocation = "https://**************.firebaseio.com/Niloy"

  let ref = FIRDatabase.database().referenceFromURL(BASE_URL_HotelLocation)

  ref.queryOrderedByChild("location").queryStartingAtValue("uttara").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

      if let result = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

          for child in result {

              let downloadURL = child.value!["image"] as! String;

              self.storage.referenceForURL(downloadURL).dataWithMaxSize(25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                  let downloadImage = UIImage(data: data!)

                  let h = Hotel()


                  h.name = child.value!["name"] as! String
                  print("Object \(count) : ",h.name)
                  h.deal = child.value!["deal"] as! String
                  h.description = child.value!["description"] as! String
                  h.distance = child.value!["distance"] as! String
                  h.latestBooking = child.value!["latestBooking"] as! String
                  h.location = child.value!["location"] as! String
                  h.image = downloadImage!

                  self.HotelObjectArray.append(h)
              })

          }   
              let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name:"yourStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
              let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SearchResultPageIdentifier") as! SearchResultPage                           
              self.navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

      }
      else {
          print("no results")
      }

      })
  ```

  }